# Get parent entity according to some property filter in child table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, filter

Id like to get all the parent that doesn't have in the signature table anything with

(Roleid 1 OR Roleid 2 OR Roleid 3) AND SignatureStatus IS <> NULL

RoleId - int: 0-13
SignatureStatus - bit: True, False, Null

I have this code but i still get the parent when i shouldn't and not getting it when i should..

```
 result = Context.APP_AuthorityHasamaForm.Where(x =>
                x.UpdateTypeId == (int)UpdateType.Unit && x.AuthorityNum == authorityUnit.AuthorityNum &&
                x.InsertDate >= authorityUnit.FromDate && x.HasamaFormStatus == (int)Status.Valid &&
               !(x.APP_SignatureAuthorityHasamaForm.Any(s =>
                    s.RoleId == (int)Role.EligibilityWorker1 || s.RoleId == (int)Role.DepartmentManager2 ||
                    s.RoleId == (int)Role.Treasurer3 && ((bool)s.SignatureStatus || !(bool)s.SignatureStatus)))).ToList();
```

Comment: Is signatureStatus nullable?

Comment: Yes, signatureStatus could by null

Comment: Did you try !s.SignatureStatus.HasValue?

Comment: I try it now after you mention it and still something not working. Even if i have one signature with only (roleId 4) i still don't get the parent table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing it to be this?

```
!(x.APP_SignatureAuthorityHasamaForm.Any(s =>
    (s.RoleId == (int)Role.EligibilityWorker1 || s.RoleId == (int)Role.DepartmentManager2 ||
    s.RoleId == (int)Role.Treasurer3) && s.SignatureStatus.HasValue))).ToList();
```

Comment: With your code if i have roleId 1-3 i get no parent even if the signatureStatus is NULL

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your class structure but here goes few fixes , put brackets outside OR condition and use .HasValue for checking  non null :

```
.Any(s =>
     (s.RoleId == (int)Role.EligibilityWorker1 || s.RoleId == (int)Role.DepartmentManager2 ||
         s.RoleId == (int)Role.Treasurer3) && ((bool)s.SignatureStatus.hasValue).ToList();
```